# Python array pointers into c++ subprocess

Tags: python, c++, arrays, subprocess, ctypes

I have a C++ code that I would like to run within a python code.  Numpy arrays are generated in this python script then sent to the dll via `ctypes`.

### TheDLL.cpp

```
    extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void DoSomeStuff(int *Array_A, int *Array_B, int *Array_C) { 

        //Do stuff here

}
```

### TheSimulation.py

```
mydll = ctypes.CDLL("TheDLL.dll")
mydll.DoSomeStuff.argtypes = [ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_int), ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_int), ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_int)]

Array_A = NumpyArrayA.ctypes.data_as(ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_int))
Array_B = NumpyArrayB.ctypes.data_as(ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_int))
Array_C = NumpyArrayC.ctypes.data_as(ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_int))

mydll.DoSomeStuff(Array_A, Array_B, Array_C)
```

`Array_A`, `Array_B` and `Array_C` have their values modified and the python script continues

The above does exactly what I need, however I noticed that `DoSomeStuff` performs very slowly as opposed to if it were compiled as an Exe and run by itself (about 15 times slower).  I tried compiling the cpp into a normal EXE, and calling it via `subprocess` in python.

### TheEXE.cpp

```
void DoSomeStuff(int *Array_A, int *Array_B, int *Array_C) {
//Do stuff here
}

    int main () {

    //Load Array_A, Array_B, Array_C from external files, separate from the python script entirely

    DoSomeStuff(Array_A, Array_B, Array_C);
    }
```

And the python is now

### TheSimulation.py

```
from subprocess import call
call(["TheEXE.exe"])
```

In terms of speed, the `subprocess` method produces the desired results, but I am not sure how I can stick those array pointers into the TheEXE.exe process in the same way I did with those `ctypes` array pointers into the DLL.  Is there any way I can replicate what I did with `ctypes` and the DLL via `subprocess` and the EXE?

Thank you all in advance and best regards,